# IOS How to upload PFFile on resuming app for example when getting interrupted by phone call?

Tags: ios, iphone, file-upload, resume

The below is code how I upload the file. This gets completely cancelled when the app is put in the background, so is there any inbuilt PFFile function to work around this, this would be the easiest solution.

```
PFFile * file = [PFFile fileWithName:filetoUpload data:data];
        [file saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

            //Something bad has ocurred
        if (![self CheckConnection])

         {
                UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The Internet connection appears to be offline " delegate:self
                                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [errorAlertView show];
            [errorAlertView release];

              [file cancel];
            }
}
```

Comment: How big is the file? Have you looked at starting a background task before and ending it in the completion block?

Comment: @Wain no, i want it to **pause** when the app goes in background not continue and **resume** when the app resumes